# Don't understand why this TypeError: must be str, not float exception occurs

Tags: python, string, web, web-scraping

```
st1= str()
c1= str()
c2= str()
EndCash = float()

page = requests.get('http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=' +
                    str(st1) + '&From=' + (c1) + '&To=' + (c2))
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
rate = tree.xpath('//span[@class="uccResultAmount"]/text()')
symbol = tree.xpath('//span[@class="uccToCurrencyCode"]/text()')

EndCash = rate + symbol
```

I am using the `requests` module and `lxml` to harvest currency rates from the Internet. I am encountering problems when doing this. I am getting a `must be str, not float` error. I'm using this line of code for a label in `tkinter` so the output of this, which is `EndCash`, should appear in the label. This code works independently but in `tkinter` it does not work

```
>>>TypeError: must be str, not float
```

on first statememt.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: The error is from  page = requests.get('http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?
       Amount=' + str(st1) + '&From='+(c1) +'&To=' + 
       (c2))

Comment: @xys234: Are you sure about what line causing the error? There's nothing in it that statement that could cause that kind of error as far as I can see because all of those variables (`st1`, `c1`, and `c2`) _are_ strings. Please [edit] your question and add a full Traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this your code should work, you have to trasform floats to string after defining them

```
page = requests.get('http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=' + str(st1) + '&From='+str(c1) +'&To=' + str(c2))
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
rate = tree.xpath('//span[@class="uccResultAmount"]/text()')
symbol = tree.xpath('//span[@class="uccToCurrencyCode"]/text()')

EndCash = str(rate + symbol)
```

Comment: The error is from  page = requests.get('http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?
       Amount=' + str(st1) + '&From='+(c1) +'&To=' + 
       (c2))

Comment: The code in your answer and the OP's question is not valid Python.

Comment: what do you mean? @martineau

Comment: The indentation of the last four statements is wrong.

Comment: i can't edit his answer, but mine is now correct @martineau

Comment: True. I don't understand what you say about transforming floats to string after defining them because `st1`, `c1`, `c2` are already strings (and `EndCash` isn't even referenced in line one).

Comment: the error affirmed that at least one of them was a float @martineau